# How to empty a Django Queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a custom QuerySet object that has several methods to chain filtering.  First, the setup for context.

```
from django.db.models import Manager, Model
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

class MyQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def some_filter(self, foo):
        return self.filter(some__chain__of__relationships__foo=foo)

class MyModelManager(Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return MyQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

class MyModel(Model):
    objects = MyModelManager()
```

Use Case:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.get_query_set()
qs = qs.filter_by_name(name).filter_by_color(color).filter_by_date(date)
```

I have a situation where I need to return an empty queryset of my object, not Django's EmptyQuerySet.

```
def filter_by_color(self, color):
    if color.is_active:
        return self.filter(some__chain__of__relationships__color=color)
    return self.empty()
```

How would I define `.empty()`?  I can't use `.none()` because the `.filter_by_date(date)` will throw an error because an EmptyQuerySet has no `.filter_by_date()` method.  I'm currently using the hack `where=['1=0']`

```
def empty(self):
    return self.extra(where=['1=0'])
```

Or...:

```
def empty(self):
    return self.filter(pk=0)
```

I would much prefer to do this in a non-hack way.

What is the Pythonic way return an empty queryset of my custom QuerySet object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Django <= 1.5, you can subclass both the `EmptyQuerySet` class and your own custom queryset class. Just override `none()` to return your custom class:

```
class MyQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def none(self):
        # prevent circular import
        from . import MyEmptyQuerySet
        return self._clone(klass=MyEmptyQuerySet)

class MyEmptyQuerySet(EmptyQuerySet, MyQuerySet):
    pass
```

In Django 1.6, the class of your queryset is still the same if you call `none()`, but through use of metaclasses and overriding `__instancecheck__`, calling `isinstance(qs.none(), EmptyQuerySet)` will still return `True`. So in Django 1.6, there is no need for custom classes or anything, your new methods on your custom queryset class are still available on an empty queryset.

Comment: I was afraid this might be the case.  I really, really didn't want to have to create my own `EmptyQuerySet`, but such is life.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
qs = qs.filter_by_name(name).filter_by_color(color)
qs = qs.filter_by_date(date) if isinstance(qs, MyQuerySet) else qs
```

That's the simplest thing I can see right now. Or filter by color at the end of the chain.

Comment: This is too specific of a use case and requires I know what order the filters will be chained.  What if any/all of the filters can return an EmptyQuerySet object?  This implementation would not be general enough.